# I'm unable to create a list from a Regex match

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm trying to extract only the "DELETE /[resource]" part from this list:

```
57.88.37.55 - - [01/Mar/2021:21:50:36 +0000] "DELETE /customers HTTP/1.1" 201 4730
244.240.70.241 - - [01/Mar/2021:21:50:36 +0000] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 400 3081
16.102.244.72 - - [01/Mar/2021:21:50:36 +0000] "PATCH /users HTTP/1.1" 200 2344
78.7.87.158 - - [01/Mar/2021:21:50:36 +0000] "DELETE /parsers HTTP/1.1" 300 2897
77.51.66.200 - - [01/Mar/2021:21:50:36 +0000] "POST /lists HTTP/1.1" 200 3364
55.12.74.229 - - [01/Mar/2021:21:50:36 +0000] "GET /customers HTTP/1.1" 200 3927
194.115.77.20 - - [01/Mar/2021:21:50:36 +0000] "GET /events HTTP/1.1" 301 2249
95.62.102.64 - - [01/Mar/2021:21:50:36 +0000] "PATCH /events HTTP/1.1" 503 4334
6.36.213.6 - - [01/Mar/2021:21:50:36 +0000] "DELETE /alerts HTTP/1.1" 403 3533
```

Using the following code:

```py
patternHTTPMethod = re.compile(r'([D]\w+\s/\w+)') #Expressão regular para identificar o método HTTP DELETE e o recurso acedido

lstHTTPMethodDel=[]
for line in fstring: 
    lstHTTPMethodDel.append(patternHTTPMethod.search(line)[0])
print(lstHTTPMethodDel)
```

(`fstring` is a variable to which I attributed the list above)

But, alas, I receive the following error:

```
lstHTTPMethodDel.append(patternHTTPMethod.search(line)[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any ideas, approaches, to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the regex matches before accessing the matched string:

```
patternHTTPMethod = re.compile(r'([D]\w+\s/\w+)')

lstHTTPMethodDel=[]
for line in fstring:
    match = patternHTTPMethod.search(line)
    if match:
        lstHTTPMethodDel.append(match[0])
print(lstHTTPMethodDel)
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found a way around this problem by inserting

```
for line in fstring: 
if patternHTTPMethodDel.search(line) is None:
        continue
    else:
        lstHTTPMethodDel.append(patternHTTPMethodDel.search(line)[0])
```

into the code

Comment: It's better to store `patternHTTPMethodDel.search(line)` in a variable though and use it  later instead of doing it twice.